# Add digital signature or iamge signature to pdf using oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Deas ,
I have a screen to view pdf file in oracle apex,  how i can add digital signature or image signature to pdf when press sign button,  it's possible or not possible , i need any way to do that , by database procedure or plugin in apex

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience this requires a 3rd party tool like [DBSign](https://dbsign.com/products/dbsign) to modify/sign the actual PDF. Neither APEX nor Oracle DB has this capability built in.